# OpenGL selection area

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl, projection

[image]

I'm currently using LWJGL but if you have a solution for OpenGL I can use that too.

Now, I'm trying to apply a selection area to a plane that I can move around with my mouse (like my terrible drawing above). I'm trying to make it flat to the plane, so it can move over any obstacles. I've considered projection texture but I dont know how to implement it. Is this a good way of solving the problem or is there any better alternative?

1. What would be the best way to implement a selection area?
2. Alternative options, pros and cons.

Edit: This will be moving over another texture if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It seems your point 2 is off-topic since it asks for a off-site resource. For the problem: If you have the intersection point with the plane in world-space, the circle can be drawn in the fragment shader without any texture projection. Just calculate the distance from the current fragment to the intersection point. If it is closer than the circle size, then color it, otherwise just display the plane.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Well explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you already know the intersection point in world space, there is a relative simple solution that doesn't require projected textures:

In the fragment shader calculate the world-space distance between the intersection point and the current fragment. When the distance between the two is smaller than the desired radius of the circle, then the selection color should be drawn. Otherwise just the normal plane is drawn.

```
float dist = length(current_ws - intersection_ws);

if (dist < circle_radius)
    //Draw overlay
else
    //Draw plane normal
```